# Will a Samsonite Laptop Backpack/Wh be considered a hand luggage on Lufthansa?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, lufthansa

I have a flight with Lufthansa Airlines, a basic economy flight from Frankfurt to Montreal.

I ask if a bag of a type **Samsonite Laptop Backpack/Wh** is allowed on the plane, knowing that its dimensions are **39 x 24 x 55 cm**. And the dimensions allowed by Lufthansa are **40 x 23 x 55 cm**.

Will it be considered an extra Checked baggage
? Will I pay additional fees?

Best regards

[image: Samsonite Unisex Laptop Backpack/Wh 55/20 Casual Daypack]

Comment: What did Lufthansa say when you asked them?

Comment: Lufthansa airlines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a soft bag and the dimensions are very close, this will be fine.

Lufthansa can be aggressive about enforcing the weight limit. 8 kg is not a whole lot and it's to exceed this. Your empty bag weighs already 2 kg. A few years ago they weighed pretty much anytime I flew with them but have recently eased up. They are more likely to weigh in Frankfurt than in Montreal (if you have a return flight)

Answer (score 1):

Provided weight limits are followed, this is a perfectly ok bag to bring on board. Lufthansa is unlikely to enforce a 1cm over the limit issue.

Comment: Do you have an official source for that? Not wanting to be picky, but the dimensions of the OP’s bag appear to exceed the maximum allowed, albeit by only a small amount

Comment: I had bought a similar and even slightly bigger bag and I was allowed through. Also, this is not a hard case luggage. Just a bit of squeeze and there is your 1cm. :)

Comment: Like all soft bags it will depend a lot on what is inside and how things are arranged.

Comment: I don't know about Lufthansa specifically, but the usual method of measuring hand baggage size is to squeeze it into a metal frame, so if there is a bit of give it will fit. (They are mostly concerned about whether it can be stowed away, rather than the unsquashed length.)

Comment: @StuartF Possible further clarification on the point you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question we would be able to answer.

According to [Lufthansa's baggage calculator page](https://www.lufthansa.com/br/en/baggage-calculator#/results), you are allowed one personal, one carry-on and one checked.

- Under the checked baggage they list the total size of 158 centimeters as length plus width plus height.
- Under the carry-on baggage they list it differently, as max 55 x 40 x 23, but not totaled.

Therefore, it is a toss up whether you will get an agent that is a stickler for being over by one centimeter, or not. However, if they do force you to check it, you will have exceeded your checked baggage allowance and have to pay for it.